# How to insert a pdf page at the very last page of a book?

Tags: pdfpages, books

I have a book class, I'm trying to add a pdf page at the very last page of my book. At the end of my latex I have :

```
\includepdf[pages={1}]{mylastpdf}
\end{document}
```

However I don't know why but after I compile the latex I still have an empty page at the end of my book and my pdf is included just before that. How can I include my pdf at the very last page ?

**Edit**

I realized that it is causes only when I have the following package in my tex file : `chapterbib` ,  `float` and `minitoc` . But I need these packages. Could you help me with this ?

Here a full example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib} %% Required
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage{float}%% Required
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{minitoc} %% Required
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Conclusion générale.}
    \lipsum[50]
    \includepdf[pages={1}]{backcover/resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need a complete example. What you describe is not the default behaviour.

Comment: @cfr  I though it was the default behaviour, thanks to your remark I found it is cause when I have three others packages - see my edit

Comment: That's why you should always include an MWE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\AtEndDocument` can be used to place the included page a little later after the possible additions of other packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib} %% Required
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{float}%% Required
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{minitoc} %% Required
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Conclusion générale.}
    \lipsum[50]
    \AtEndDocument{\includepdf[pages={1}]{example-image-a}}
\end{document}
```

The reason are several bugs in `minitoc`. At some point it executes `\mtc@hints@checklongext` in `\AtEndDocument`. It contains lots of:

```
\if@mtc@<package>Loaded\else
  \if@mtc@<package>Loaded@a@
    \mtc@PackageWarningNoLine[...]{...}{...}
  \fi
\fi
```

The line end after the last argument of `\mtc@PackageWarningNoLine` should be commented to prevent a potential white space leaking in.

The real problem, however, is the following pattern:

```
\if@mtc@<package>Loaded@\
   \mtcPackageInfo[...]{...}{...}
\fi
```

It looks like a copy/paste error. The intention was to delete the `\else`, but the backslash remains. Combined with the normal end of line it becomes `\␣` (backslash and space), which forces a space, which is *not* ignored in vertical mode, but it forces a new paragraph with this space. The vertical list is now no longer empty and TeX sets an additional page with some spaces.